# acl for edit post page?

Tags: php, zend-framework, authorization

i wonder if i shld use an ACL rule (PHP/`Zend_Acl` in my case) for something as small as a edit post page? i guess the criteria to allow users to edit a post will be

- owner of post
- editors/moderators/admin

the question will be if yes (to use acl), how can i define it (i am using `Zend_Acl` but if u give me some code example, i might be able to translate it).

acl's i think will generally be defined at application start/bootstrap. in this case, its partially dynamic as in i must chk against the logged in user.

or will a simple if else suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its called Assertions

- [Dynamic Assertions in Zend Framework](http://ralphschindler.com/2009/08/13/dynamic-assertions-for-zend_acl-in-zf)
- [Docs: Assertions](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html)