# How is ACL implemented

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

i am using `Zend_Acl`, PHP and is wondering how shld ACLs be implemented.

shld every page be a resource and i *always* query the acl to see if a user is authorized? i guess i must use this if i want to use a controller plugin (can be setup to run on every request) to check if a user is allowed?

or do i just put the query code where i need it? eg. at the top of pages i need to query the acl? then in pages publicly available, i just skip it? may get troublesome if the application gets big?

Comment: possible duplicate of [acl for edit post page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353075/acl-for-edit-post-page), by the same author.

Comment: hmm, in this question, i am actually asking if i shld have acl query code in every page vs that page as how to have more dynamic acl query. but thats my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i just answer this question then close it

what i did now was have a controller plugin that sets its resource based on controller name and privilege based on action name. then query the acl based on that

still under development, but what i currently have look like http://pastebin.com/9BYzms7W